# Do any English synonyms have exactly the same meaning?

Tags: synonyms, semantics, language-evolution

*Air* and *breeze* are termed as synonyms but they do not mean the same thing. *Air* is a general term while *breeze* would actually mean a cool flowing air.

Do we actually have **exact synonyms** for nouns in English?

In other languages, for example Hindi, we have 4–5 words meaning exactly the same thing; *Hawa*, *Vayu*, and *Pawan* all mean “air”.

Comment: There's no such thing as an exact synonym in English, and I honestly doubt there is one in Hindi or any other language. That's just not how (I understand) languages works. But of course, speaking only English, I can't back up that claim or gainsay you with respect to *hawa*, *vayu*, *pawan*, etc. But can you honestly tell me there are *no* contexts where, for example, your happily use *vayu*, but *pawan* simply wouldn't work? Honk about it in detail.

Comment: @DanBron Although Hindi is my mother tongue but I do not claim academic fluency in Hindi. I haven't studied the language post high school. But I cant think of any example where you cannot substitute _pawan_ with with _vayu_ .However you cannot use _sameer_ another term related to air, meaning breeze more precisely in place to _vayu_

Comment: @DanBron I have been told that in more ancient language like Sanskrit and Arabic there were many words meaning exactly the same thing. People say that classical Arabic had more than 500 words for horse and alcoholic beverages

Comment: @ShiyamHoda People also say the Eskimos have 100 words for snow, but [it's not true](https://www.theatlantic.com/notes/2016/01/mini-object-lesson-no-there-are-not-a-hundred-eskimo-words-for-snow/426651/). It's just an urban legend. Having said that, the general thrust of the legend is *against* perfect synonymy: the idea is that Eskimos, living in the far north, with snow being a part of their daily lives, are on much more familiar and intimate terms with if, so they have 100 different words for different *kinds* is snow. Dry snow, wet snow, blowing snow, the snow between the dogs' toes, etc.

Comment: I can easily think of tens, if not hundreds, of words in English for alcoholic beverages, but that does by no means make them synonyms. Having a " word for x" does not mean that word is a synonym.

Comment: Google translate seems to be sure that _hawa_ is Malay, not Hindi (so it may well be a loan word in Hindi?), and that while _pavan_ is translated solely as _air_, _vayu_ can also mean breeze or wind. So I suspect that although using _vayu_ instead of _pavan_ is never a problem, it might not always work the other way around.

Comment: @oerkelens I am Indian and I can tell you that hawa, pawan and vayu all mean air/wind. Hindi-Urdu is a dual language with a 'twin vocabulary' where 'hawa' comes from the Urdu side and 'vayu' and 'pavan' are words coming from Sanskrit. They can be used interchangeably to mean basically the same thing, but the colloquial term is 'hawa' and the word 'pawan' for breeze is literary/poetic. 'Vayu' usually means air rather than breeze and is often used in factual context as in 'clean air'/'fresh air' _ *while pavan is translated solely as air, vayu can also mean breeze or wind* _ its other way round!

Comment: @EnglishStudent I'm not surprised Google wasn't exact. However, your comment does show that the words are used in different registers and contexts, which means that they are not 100% interchangeable. In English, _loo_ and _toilet_ may be semantically exchangeable, but they are not in all cases 100% interchangeable due to context and register.

Comment: @oerkelens very true -- OP is *hoist on his own petard* -- my reply would be that no language has 100% exact synonyms, because when a few words are perfectly interchangeable, one or more of those words will tend to become redundant and either disappear by disuse or get redefined as the language evolves.

Comment: There is such a thing as an exact synonym, but it is not exactly common. Very often exact synonyms are alternative terms for very specific and clearly demarcated objects. There are quite a few species of birds or kinds of fruits and flowers that have several names in English, for example. Some of these may be dialectal (like _eggplant_ and _aubergine_), but not all; _furze_ and _gorse_ refer to the exact same plant to most people, and the difference between the two is not based on dialect, register, etc.

Comment: There is also the case of morphological synonymity, which is when a particular morphological form of a word has several possibly surface forms with no difference in meaning. _Dive_ and _dove_ are both possible surface forms for the past tense of the verb _dive_, for example, although _dove_ is mostly restricted to informal, North American usage. In Finnish, the genitive plural of nouns and adjectives is formed with either _-(i)den_ or _-(i)tten_, in (as far as I know) free variation; in Donegal Irish, ‘I say’ is randomly _abraim_ or _deirim_; etc.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet you make a very good point that 100% interchangeable 'exact synonyms' do exist but are rare, such as eggplant and aubergine -- what about *orca* and *killer whale?*

Comment: @EnglishStudent ~ they are still not exact synonyms, even when they are two nouns with the same referent. If there are two words available, they pretty well must have different connotations. Orca, for example, is probably more 'scientific' than killer whale, while killer whale is more 'dramatic' by focussing on the predatory behaviour of the creature.

Comment: @Roaring Fish I educated myself and found you are very right: *Orcinus orca* is the scientific name for 'killer whale', which is the common name; however the killer whale is routinely called orca in common language as well, mainly in USA (I think) -- probably to avoid the negative connotations of 'killer' -- in further support of their possibly being 'exact synonyms' I also found 'orca' and 'killer whale' used alternately and interchangeably in this online article: [A 'Suicidal' Killer Whale Beached Itself(...)](http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/videos/a45576/seaworld-whale-beaches-itself/)

Comment: @DanBron Your comments were interesting to me; I posted an answer thanks to them.

Comment: This doesn't look like an exact duplicate of the cited question to me; that one asks if *all* synonyms are exact replacements (clear answer: no) whereas this one appears to be asking whether *any* synonyms are perfectly interchangeable (apparent answer: rarely, but yes).

Comment: @oerkelens Malay and Hindi have tons of words in common because both Arabic and Sanskrit flowed heavily into both of them.

Answer (score 7):

The late [Daniel H. H. Ingalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_H._H._Ingalls_Sr.), in his book of translation *Sanskrit Poetry from Vidyākara's “Treasury”*, touches on this matter in [his introduction](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~pehook/ingalls.pdf). Although he is talking about Sanskrit for English readers, I find such statements useful in telling those who know Sanskrit something about English (or at least its speakers):

> Sanskrit not only has an enormous vocabulary; it has also a larger choice of synonyms than any other language I know. In a natural language there are probably no synonyms. Of course, one can go to a thesaurus and find what are called synonyms. For the English word ‘house’ one may find ‘dwelling,’ ‘residence,’ ‘tenement,’ ‘abode,’ and so on. But these are not true synonyms as one can see the moment one tries to interchange them. One cannot say of the Vanderbilts that they lived in a large tenement in Newport, Rhode Island. Each word in English has connotations that it cannot shed and that permit it to be used only in an appropriate social and emotional setting. There is even a genre of English humor, perhaps best exemplified by S. J. Perelman, which gains its effect by dropping words into a setting which cries out, so to speak, against their connotations. This form of humor was never developed beyond a rudimentary stage in Sanskrit, for while Sanskrit distinguishes, it is true, between poetic words and matter-of-fact words, it achieves within each of these categories an extraordinary degree of synonymity. The poetic words for house in Sanskrit—and Sanskrit has far more words for this object than English—differ chiefly in sound and etymology. They are not bound to a particular social or emotional situation. Thus, *veśman* is literally the place where one enters, *sadman* the place where one sits down, *vastya* the place where one dwells, *nilaya* and *ālaya* the place where one alights or comes to rest. These words are far more interchangeable than the English ones. *Nilaya* will do for the dwelling of a king or a farmer or a crow.

In the [context](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~pehook/ingalls.pdf) that surrounds these words, he attributes this difference (English doesn't have true synonyms, Sanskrit has true synonyms) to the fact that Sanskrit was used in an “educated” setting and was thus not a “natural” language: he thinks that it is Sanskrit that is odd here by having true synonyms, because “natural” languages never do. (He may touch on similar matters in his [*Some Problems in the Translation of Sanskrit Poetry*](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/mealac/pritchett/00litlinks/txt_ingalls_skttrans_1982.pdf); I'll have to reread it.)

Of course, everyone likely finds their own language and culture natural, and considers deviations from that “norm” as needing explanation. My personal experience, with a different Indian language (and from a different language family) than the OP’s, is that even “natural” languages do indeed have at least occasional synonyms with no difference in meaning or social/emotional connotation.

Either way, I find it informative that (at least some) people from an Anglophone culture consider it natural for there to exist no true synonyms. I hope that answers your question!

Comment: I have somehow managed to post this answer *after* the question was closed as duplicate. Race condition in StackExchange code?

Comment: This is a *fantastic* answer. Thank you for posting it!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Were you posting this from a mobile site or app? That's one way to do so, and it still remains an option.